# password not accepted on ubuntu login page

Tags: login

I am using a hp chromebook 14. When I go to the login page of ubuntu I correctly spell my user and password but it says `incorrect login`.

This was working fine yesterday when I installed it but now I can't log in. I'm not sure how to change the password in chrome os terminal because I cant reach the terminal in ubuntu.

Please send me the code I would need to type in chrome os terminal to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Just press Ctrl+Alt+F2 and try to login with no X.  You should login with root account. Then you could change the user password with command like this:
passwd 
Press  Ctrl+Alt+F7 or something to get graphic back.

Answer (score 0):

restart and go to recovery mode for your os, see whether an option named `root` is there, if so choose it by navigating to root and press enter. then type `passwd` and enter. this will ask for your new UNIX password. for changing password of a specific user, you have to do `passwd uid`,where `uid` should be replaced with your username.